# Xcode: Program ended with exit code: 255

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am trying to read a csv file into C++, but I kept got the message that "Program ended with exit code:255". I tried restart the Xcode, restart the Mac, but it did not work. Is anyone have the same problem?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// defind the type of longitude and latitude as the key

typedef struct {
    double lat;
    double lon;
} location;

struct Stud{
    location key;
    string date;
    double temp;
    double concen;
    string descrip;
};


int main()
{

    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    Stud items;

    ifstream file("data.csv");

    if( !file.is_open()) {

        cout << "File not found." << endl;
        exit(-1);

    }

    while ( getline( file, line) ) { // To get the number of lines in        the file
        counter++;
    }

    Stud* item = new Stud[counter]; // Add number to structured array

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

        file >> item[i].date >> item[i].key.lon>> item[i].key.lat>>     item[i].temp >> item[i].concen >> item[i].descrip;

}

    cout << item[1].date << endl;

    file.close();

    return 0;
   }
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: does `data.csv` exist? does it print "File not found." ?

Comment: You should explain what your code does, and provide the input (csv) that you are trying to use.

Comment: Yes, I have the file in the same directory. I couldn't figure out why?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. My code is to read a csv file to a data structure in C++. The csv file has six columns: date(string), longitude(double), latitude(double), temperature(double), concentration(double), and description(string).

Comment: `exit(-1);` - you do know that this will end up as a positive value - right? If you look up the documentation for `exit` you'll see "The exit() function causes normal process termination and the value of status & 0377 is returned to the parent" - so forget about checking for negative exit codes... Why don't you just use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and/or `EXIT_FAILURE`?

Comment: Do you mean delete this line "exit(-1);"?

Comment: It still didn't work. But give me a new error "File not found.
\277\377\240
Program ended with exit code: 0" , Can you help me to identify the problem? Thanks a lot! @JesperJuhl

Comment: @Ping Hou No, of course I don't mean to just delete the line. I *mean* that you should *understand* that return values from main are zero or a positive number and there are exactly two well defined constants you can use. Just returning `-1` clearly shows you have no clue what exit codes are for...

Comment: apparently, it can either not find, or can't open `data.csv. please ensure the file is in the current directory when you run your program and is readable

Comment: How many rows are in each column?  How many structs do you expect to end up with?  Are they to be collected into an array?  Your question is unclear and it is not possible to tell what your intentions are from the code you provide.